# Converting integer array to equivalent opencv mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an integer array with 81920 elements and its name is label. The elements of this array are something like: 0,1,2,7,... (small integer values)
I am trying to convert this integer array to an OpenCV mat. I used this code:

```
int label[81920];
//Fill label matrix
cv::Mat LabelsMat = cv::Mat(81920, 1, CV_32FC1, label);
```

But when I use this instruction for showing LabelsMat as output:

```
cout << "LabelsMat = "<< endl << " "  << LabelsMat << endl << endl;
```

instead of recieving corresponding data with label[] like 2, 7, 4, etc, I recieve some wrong results like:

"0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.7508865e-14, 4.5704751e-41, 2.3237829e-17, 4.5704751e-41, 6.1657132e-44, 0, 1.9651262e-13, 4.5704751e-41, -9.1165924e+11,..."

Can any one tell me kindly where is my fault and why my results are incorrect.
I appropriate your help.

Comment: use `CV_32SC1` , not `CV_32FC1`

Comment: Thanks, but this time I receive some number like: " -324483898; 32741; 44; 0; -219778840; 32741; 337130304; 32767; -219786826; 32741; -241775467; 32741; 0; 0; 13; 0; -324483898; 32741; 2; 0; -219778840; 32741; -219840575; 32741; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 31; 0; 0; 0; 0 " as the result, bigger numbers but still incorrect :(

Comment: if your `int label[81920];` goes out of scope, before you're done with `LabelsMat`, you'll have to clone() it.

Comment: But the label matrix does not go out of scope...

Comment: Even I tried: 
for (int i=0;i<81920;++i)
 LabelsMat.at<int>(i)=label[i];
 but still same problem!